# How do you implement a www to naked domain redirect in Google Apps with Flask?

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, godaddy, google-workspace

I see loads of tutorials about naked domain to `www` domain redirects, but what if I want to do it the other way around (`www.example.com` -> `example.com`)?

My app is on Google Apps with Flask deployed, and my domain is registered with GoDaddy.

Comment: I'm not using vhost or apache

Comment: What web server are you using? This will help. I am sure we have an IIS and Nginx example somewhere.

Comment: I'm using a google cloud app in flask

Answer (score 2):

`www.` is an automatic alias. (See http://www.chickenaday.appspot.com/ vs http://chickenaday.appspot.com/). Why force the user?

If you do want to redirect, you could try this untested snippet of slightly modified code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964868/3164117:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse

@app.before_request
def redirect_nonwww():
    """Redirect www requests to non-www."""
    urlparts = urlparse(request.url)
    if urlparts.netloc == 'www.example.com':
        urlparts_list = list(urlparts)
        urlparts_list[1] = 'example.com'
        redirect(urlunparse(urlparts_list), code=301)
```

Comment: Why force the user? Because a browser app that is started with www cannot call its backend for APIs that are without www due to the Same Origin Policy. Github only uses the naked domain and any attempt to enter www will redirect to the naked domain.